# Replace all url start with " m." to without ".m" ( m.example.com/index.html To example.com/index.html)

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects

Our previous website has one sub directory called `"mobile"`. So in the main pages we write code if it is screen size less than 640px then go to mobile/ folder .

```
<link href="http://mobile.example.com/index.html/" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" rel="alternate" />
```

For example, someone takes `example.com/index.html`  website from mobile, they are redirected to `mobile.example.com/index.html`.

Now we developed a new website that is responsive & in that files we remove the redirection code. But some people bookmarked our previous mobile page url .

So we want to redirect all `mobile.example.com/file` to `example.com/file`.

How can we do this?

Comment: You may be using a "subdirectory" in your underlying file system implementation, but your example shows a _subdomain_, not a subdirectory. Also, the HTML snippet you show does not a trigger a "redirect", which you seem to imply?

Answer (score 2):

Based very specifically on the information that you provided in your question, all you need to do is create a file called `.htaccess` in the doc root (web / httpdocs / www folder) of `mobile.example.com` (inside your "mobile" directory) and put in the code below. Be sure to add the most relevant version that best fits your circumstances, as indicated below:

**1. Preferred version of your domain's URL is "non-www"**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^index.html(.*)$ http://example.com/index.html$1 [R=301,NC]
```

**2. Preferred version of your domain's URL is the "www" version**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^index.html(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.html$1 [R=301,NC]
```

As for redirecting individual pages to other individual pages, as long as the URLs are identical, and the only difference is the mobile subdomain, then you should be good to go. *I have not tested this, please provide feedback!*

On the other hand, if URIs for each individual directory (i.e. `/directory/`) or page (i.e. `/page.html`) on your old mobile version are different than the non-mobile version, all that you would need to..

**Page to Page Redirect from subdomain:**

```
Redirect 301 "/old-page.html" "http://www.example.com/new-page.html"
```

Remember, this is all taking place on the `.htaccess` file you created within the mobile folder.

Comment: @MrWhite would you mind telling me how to properly format the information in my answer - I cannot decipher how to modify correctly in future answers. Thank you for your time & help!

Comment: You can view my edits by checking the [edit history on your answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/110833/revisions) (use the "side-by-side markdown" option). When editing your answer you can click the `?` (help menu) to get more editing help. From there you can also get [advanced help](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code). The main reason for my edit was that you had formatted your blocks of code as "quotations", rather than "code blocks" (indent by 4 spaces) - this option is on the toolbar. Apart from being harder to read, some characters can get omitted.

Comment: I did review your edits, and knew that the highlighted color had changed, but you answered my question in the latter part of your comment. Thanks for your help!